# How to include parents when downloading a file using wget

Tags: linux, wget

When you want to copy a file using `cp` you can use `--parents` argument so that it creates corresponding parents directories while copying the file. Now imagine I want to download a file which has parents on the remote server; how can I similarly create the path.

Example:

`wget https://example.com/path/css/style.css`

I want the file to be downloaded into:

`./path/css/style.css`

Comment: Duplicate on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange: [Download files and create same file structure as the source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72240/download-files-and-create-same-file-structure-as-the-source)